# react native - image is not showing

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have this value  `value="require('../assets/alert.png')"`
as setValue to firestore,
I retrieve this value and try to do `<Image source={marker.img} style={{width: 42, height: 42}} />`
but image is not showing.
(the data I get from DB is :  `require('../assets/alert.png')`

Edited:
these are the type of markers with icons I want to use. so User get to choose what type of marker he wants

```
 <Image source={require('../assets/marker.png')} style={{width: 32, height: 32}} />
                <RadioButton value="marker"  />
                <Text>marker</Text>
                <Image source={require('../assets/info.png')} style={{width: 32, height: 32}} />
                <RadioButton value="info" />
                <Text>alert</Text>
                <Image source={require('../assets/alert.png')} style={{width: 32, height: 32}} />
                <RadioButton value="alert" />
```

then I add the marker to firebase.

For now I used:

```
 { marker.img=='alert'? <Image source={require('../assets/alert.png')} style={{width: 42, height: 42}} />:
                marker.img=='info'? <Image source={require('../assets/info.png')} style={{width: 42, height: 42}} />:
                <Image source={require('../assets/marker.png')} onLoad={this.stopRendering} style={{width: 42, height: 42}} />
              }
```

Is there any better way to do so? I tried to get the source as I mentioned before.

I wanted to use  and see the picture instead all of the if

Comment: for now I fixed by using if method on render, for each value i render its own picture.

Comment: please post more code so we can understand better what seems to be the problem

Comment: I added more code including my current fix